# The content of element type “struts-config” must match “(datasource?,form-beans?

Tags: java, eclipse, struts, dtd, struts-config

I wrote a small struts application with a login page and registration page.
If I login I get a success page. If i register, i will check the password and confirm password fileds if they match i get a success page else failure page.

I did not use any database. I wrote the required Form Beans, Action Classes of those.

In `struts-config.xml` it is showing an error at the `<struts-config>` tag:

> "The content of element type “struts-config” must match
>   “(datasource?,form-beans?,global-forwards?,action-mapping?)"

How to resolve this problem? I am using Eclipse as my IDE.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, the `struts-config.xml` is invalid according to the schema, but as the app is working, it's only a validation issue. To expand on *why* it is invalid in the context of *the order of the child elements* - If the validator is telling you that...

> The content of element type “struts-config” must match
>   “(datasource?,form-beans?,global-forwards?,action-mapping?")

...then that means that e.g. (reduced examples for brevity):

```
<struts-config>
  <datasource>...</datasource>
  <form-beans>...</form-beans>
  <global-forwards>...</global-forwards>
  <action-mapping>...</action-mapping>
</struts-config>
```

...is a valid implementation of the schema, while e.g. ...

```
<struts-config>
  <datasource>...</datasource>
  <global-forwards>...</global-forwards>
  <form-beans>...</form-beans>
  <action-mapping>...</action-mapping>
</struts-config>
```

...is not. This, by the way, is due to the fact that the [Struts 1.0 DTD in question](http://struts.apache.org/dtds/struts-config_1_0.dtd) says...

```
<!ELEMENT struts-config (data-sources?,form-beans?,global-forwards?,action-mappings?)>
```

...and by that demands a certain order of child elements. This is not something that the DTD authors do inadvertently, but due to fact that:

> Declaring unordered lists with occurrence constraints in DTD will
>   often result in long or complicated looking declarations. <sup>[1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7833274/1529709)</sup>

Answer (score 1):

**Your struts-config.xml file is invalid.**

Struts-config.xml is an XML file and as such can be validated against a [DTD](http://www.w3schools.com/dtd/default.asp) or an [XML-Schema](http://www.w3schools.com/schema/default.asp).

The error you are seeing in Eclipse is a result of the struts-config.xml file being validated against its DTD and the validation fails. Most likely it is expecting your tags to be in a specific order and you didn't write them that way, you added tags that are not specified in the DTD, you misspelled some tag etc.

Look at the struts-config DTD and then at your struts-config.xml file to see where they differ.

P.S. there are more versions of the DTD so make sure you are looking at the right one.

http://struts.apache.org/dtds/struts-config_1_0.dtd
http://struts.apache.org/dtds/struts-config_1_1.dtd
http://struts.apache.org/dtds/struts-config_1_2.dtd
http://struts.apache.org/dtds/struts-config_1_3.dtd
http://struts.apache.org/dtds/struts-config_1_4.dtd

Answer (score 0):

The elements' order matter. For example 
`<form-beans></form-beans>` element
must be before 
`<global-forwards></global-forwards>` element etc.

Answer (score 0):

I am using `struts-config_1_3.dtd`. I also got the same error in `struts-config.xml` when I added `<global-forwards>` tag in `struts-config.xml`.

> ("The content of element type “struts-config” must match
>   “(datasource?,form-beans?,global-forwards?,action-mapping?)")

I added `<global-forwards>` tag after `<action-mapping>` tag, because of that it was throwing error.
As the error description says, the order of the tags should be

```xml
<datasource></datasource>

<form-beans></form-beans>

<global-forwards></global-forwards>

<action-mapping></action-mapping>
```

So i changed my `<global-forwards>` before `<action-mapping>`. And it worked for me.

Hope this information help someone.