# XSD - xs:all rewritten as deterministic dtd

Tags: xml, xsd, dtd

Following xsd part is given:

```
<xs:element name="root">
    <xs:complexType>
        <xs:all>
            <xs:element minOccurs="1" name="box-type-1"/>
            <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="box-type-2"/>
            <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="box-type-3"/>
            <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="box-type-4"/>
        </xs:all>
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
```

[xs:type is irrelevant]

Please see: https://stackoverflow.com/a/7833274/6805256

The linked answer shows the DTD equivalent of a similar schema **but** I can't adapt it to my needs and precise case.

EDIT: I removed the nonsense-part of my question. The question is perfectly answered.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not completely clear what problems you are encountering; to have something concrete to work with, I'll assume that the reason you cannot adapt the answer you cite to your problem is that you don't understand how it works.

The content model you give allows the elements `box-type-1` through `box-type-4` to occur in any order; since there are four elements, there are 4! = 4*3*2*1 = 24 possible sequences.  A simple regular expression in DTD-like syntax would look something like this; for brevity, I'm going to call the elements `b1`, `b2`, `b3`, `b4`.

```
( (b1, b2, b3, b4)
| (b1, b2, b4, b3)
| (b1, b3, b2, b4)
| (b1, b3, b4, b2)
| (b1, b4, b2, b3) 
| (b1, b4, b2, b3)

| (b2, b1, b3, b4) 
| (b2, b1, b4, b3) 
| (b2, b3, b1, b4) 
| (b2, b3, b4, b1) 
| (b2, b4, b1, b3) 
| (b2, b4, b3, b1) 

| (b3, b1, b2, b4) 
| (b3, b1, b4, b2) 
| (b3, b2, b1, b4) 
| (b3, b2, b4, b1) 
| (b3, b4, b1, b2) 
| (b3, b4, b2, b1) 

| (b4, b1, b2, b3) 
| (b4, b1, b3, b2) 
| (b4, b2, b1, b3) 
| (b4, b2, b3, b1) 
| (b4, b3, b1, b2) 
| (b4, b3, b2, b1) 
)
```

So far, so good, but there are two complications:  first, content models are required to be *deterministic* in both XML DTDs and XSD schemas. That means, it must always be possible to match elements in the content to specific tokens (or xsd:element elements) in the content model without looking ahead.  But an initial `b1` in the content could match any of the first six occurrences of `b1` in the content model.  That's not allowed, so we need to rewrite the content model to eliminate the non-determinism.

So we rewrite the expression, exploiting the algebraic identity which observes that for sequences, ((*x* *y* *abc*) | (*x* *z* *def*)) is equal to (*x* ((*y* *abc*) | (*z* *def*))).  If we fold common prefixes together as suggested by that identity, then we produce a deterministic expression which recognizes exactly the same language:

```
( (b1, ( (b2, ( (b3, b4) | (b4, b3) )) 
       | (b3, ( (b2, b4) | (b4, b2) ))
       | (b4, ( (b2, b3) | (b3, b2) )) ))
| (b2, ( (b1, ( (b3, b4) | (b4, b3) )) 
       | (b3, ( (b1, b4) | (b4, b1) ))
       | (b4, ( (b1, b3) | (b3, b1) )) )) 
| (b3, ( (b1, ( (b2, b4) | (b4, b2) )) 
       | (b2, ( (b1, b4) | (b4, b1) ))
       | (b4, ( (b1, b2) | (b2, b1) )) )) 
| (b4, ( (b1, ( (b2, b3) | (b3, b2) ))
       | (b2, ( (b1, b3) | (b3, b1) )) 
       | (b3, ( (b1, b2) | (b2, b1) )) )) )
```

Now we hit the second complication:  this is not quite the language we want, since it makes all four element obligatory.

A simple approach to making `b2`-`b4` optional would be to add a question mark to each of them in the expression, so it would have a form something like this:

```
( (b1, ( (b2?, ( (b3?, b4?) | (b4?, b3?) )) 
       | (b3?, ( (b2?, b4?) | (b4?, b2?) ))
       | (b4?, ( (b2?, b3?) | (b3?, b2?) )) ))
| (b2?, ... )
| (b3?, ... )
| (b4?, ... ) )
```

But this re-introduces non-determinism:  the input sequence `b1`, `b2` matches five ways just in the part of the expression shown.  The correct fix is to observe that while ((*x*?, *y*?) | (*y*?, *x*?)) is non-deterministic, the expression ((*x*, *y*?) | (*y*, *x*?))? is deterministic and accepts the same language.  Applying this principle allows us to rewrite our expression appropriately:

```
( (b1, ( (b2, ( (b3, b4?) | (b4, b3?) )?) 
       | (b3, ( (b2, b4?) | (b4, b2?) )?)
       | (b4, ( (b2, b3?) | (b3, b2?) )?) )?)
| (b2, ( (b1, ( (b3, b4?) | (b4, b3?) )?) 
       | (b3, ( (b1, b4?) | (b4, b1) ))
       | (b4, ( (b1, b3?) | (b3, b1) )) )) 
| (b3, ( (b1, ( (b2, b4?) | (b4, b2?) )?) 
       | (b2, ( (b1, b4?) | (b4, b1) ))
       | (b4, ( (b1, b2?) | (b2, b1) )) )) 
| (b4, ( (b1, ( (b2, b3?) | (b3, b2?) )?)
       | (b2, ( (b1, b3?) | (b3, b1) )) 
       | (b3, ( (b1, b2?) | (b2, b1) )) )) )
```

Note that we do not mark any token to the left of the first `b1` as optional, because that would be unnecessary and undesirable.  Unnecessary because the we can always without loss of generality assume that optional elements which don't appear in the input being validated were omitted from  the end of one of the permutations given above.  Undesirable because it would also re-introduce non-determinism.

The translation from this expression into XSD is straightforward and I leave it as an exercise for the reader.

[***Note for XML geeks reading this:***  Others may stop reading now.]

The XQuery function which I wrote to generate the left-folded expression without question marks may be of interest:

```
declare function local:all-to-choice-of-seq(
  $ids as xs:string*
) as xs:string { 
  let $n := count($ids)
  return if ($n eq 1) then $ids
  else '( ' || 
       string-join( for $id in $ids
       let $rest := $ids[. ne $id]
       return '(' || $id || ', ' 
              || local:all-to-choice-of-seq($rest) || ')',
       ' | ')
       || ' )'
};
```

Invocation:

```
let $gis := ('b1', 'b2', 'b3', 'b4')
return local:all-to-choice-of-seq( $gis )
```

A simple extension to make some elements required and others optional would be:

```
declare function local:all-to-choice-of-seq2(
  $req as xs:string*,
  $opt as xs:string*
) as xs:string { 
  local:all-to-choice-of-seq-aux(($req,$opt), $req)
};

declare function local:all-to-choice-of-seq-aux(
  $ids as xs:string*,
  $req as xs:string* 
) as xs:string { 
  let $n := count($ids)
  return 
  if ($n eq 1) then 
     if (exists($req)) then $ids else $ids || '?'
  else '( ' || 
       string-join( for $id in $ids
       let $rest := $ids[. ne $id],
           $req2 := $req[. ne $id]
       return '(' || $id || ', ' 
              || local:all-to-choice-of-seq-aux($rest, $req2) || ')'
              || (if (exists($req)) then '' else '?'),
       ' | ')
       || ' )'
};
```

Invocation:  `local:all-to-choice-of-seq2( 'b1', ('b2', 'b3', 'b4') )`

But this inserts more question marks than are strictly necessary; I have not found a good way (or, to be more honest, *any* way) to emit '?' only when necessary.

Comment: Impressiv + your assumption was correct. Thanks a lot for your invested time. I like and understand the geek part (un)fortunately.