# Why must a DTD be determinisitc?

Tags: dtd, deterministic

I've done some research for a project I'm working on.
While this search I came across multiple comments in forums, which stated a DTD has to be deterministic. (e.g. [XML, DTD: how to make the order not important](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4744507/xml-dtd-how-to-make-the-order-not-important/7833274#7833274))

Until now I haven't found a scientific trustful source, which explained or confirmed this these.

So my questions are, do DTDs have to be deterministic?
If this is true, why? Is there a specification defining this and can where can I find it?

Comment: You're right, thank you